# Hierarchical forecasting packages - No trend removal or stationary check?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, mathematical-statistics, forecasting, predictive-models

I have sales data for which I would like to predict what will be the sales for each product at the product level, product store level, product store and region level etc.

To solve this problem, I came across multiple tutorials for hierarchical forecasting such as listed [here](https://github.com/Nixtla/hierarchicalforecast) in Nixtla hierarchical forecast and [here](https://medium.com/unit8-machine-learning-publication/hierarchical-forecast-reconciliation-with-darts-8b4b058bb543) using DARTS package.

While I have limited understanding of time series, I always thought that we should check for trend and stationarity of a time series before we do forecast. But in all these tutorials, I don't see that step being done.

Does this mean, these packages do it internally? I am sure that I am making a mistake somewhere as these packages are used widely by users. So, can someone shed some light on these packages and whether we need to do all those time series differencing, trend removal and stationarity removal etc?

Comment: Checking trend and stationarity is not always necessary. An auto-ARIMA method will deal with this automatically, and so will exponential smoothing. Hierarchical forecast reconciliation is a step that post-processes *any* expectation forecast, so I would assume that these packages call some other forecasting tools that calculate the original forecasts in a graceful way.

Comment: All: please don't close this as "software-related". Answering this does require statistical understanding, [so please leave it open per here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5985/1352). (Actually, there is an example on a related hierarchical forecasting question at that thread.)